# Why is sql server changing the value of the minimum and maximum memory?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 x64 instance. I tried to change the Minimum and Maximum memory to 60 MB and 2000 MB using Management Studio (Server Properties->Memory). When I close and reopen Management Studio I see those values still there. However, when I restart the SQL service, I go back to the Server Properties in Management Studio and I see that both Minimum and Maximum memory are now set to 4091 MB.

Is SQL Server changing those values by itself?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL doesn't change those values for you.  Just to rule out the obvious, are you sure you're looking at the same SQL instance  where you're looking at it the second time?

On the SQL instance in question, run this and see what the values are for in the `config_value` column for `min server memory (MB)` and `max server memory (MB)`

```
sp_configure "show advanced options",1
reconfigure
GO
sp_configure
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like another application was setting the memory settings.